# Adwords Array in Python, has no attribute 'get'

Tags: python, mysql, arrays

I am trying to figure out why my Array generated by the Adwords API has no attribute 'get'.

Here is the URL to the example:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-python-lib/blob/master/examples/adwords/v201506/basic_operations/add_text_ads.py

It just returns me:

```
AttributeError: 'AdGroupAd' object has no attribute 'get'
```

The array isnt empty, i just wanna check if in my 2 demensional array things like ad['ad']['url'] exists, before i insert anything into my mysql database.
I tested it with: `if ad in ad.get(url, {}):`

Anyone can help? Thanks.

Edit: Solved by using:

if "url" in ad['ad']:

Answer (score 0):

A little off topic regarding Python naming conventions - there is no such thing as `array` in Python (well there is but is called a `list`). The name you look for is [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries).

Regarding your problem - it seems to me that you have a variable names clash in your test:
`if ad in ad.get(url, {}):`.
Your variables `ad` is of `AdGroupAd` type but when you compare it like you do, the 2nd `ad` is also of `AdGroupAd` type, because you cannot bind 2 different objects to one name:

```
>>> ad = {'a': 'foo'}
>>> ad = 1
>>> if ad in ad.get('c', {}):
...     pass
... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get'
```

Just name the `AdGroupAd` object with another name and it should work fine:
`if ad in ads.get(url, {}):`

Comment: That dosent works, returns me the same error the object has no attribute 'get'

Comment: Solved with  if "url" in ad['ad']: Thanks.